# How can I do an EF Linq query, including a subset of related entities

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework, sql-server-2012

I have the following classes:

```
public class Problem
{
    public Problem()
    {
        this.Questions = new HashSet<Question>();
        this.Solutions = new HashSet<Solution>();
    }
    public int ProblemId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Question> Questions { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Solution> Solutions { get; set; }
}
public class Question
{
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public int ProblemId { get; set; }
    public int QuestionStatusId { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }
    public virtual Problem Problem { get; set; }
}
public class Solution
{
    public int SolutionId { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public int ProblemId { get; set; }
    public bool? Correct { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }
    public virtual Problem Problem { get; set; }
}
```

Can someone help me with LINQ for my EF6,1 SQL Server 2012.

What I would like to do is to get a List that contains only a subset of the data. In this case I would like the Notes properties in Problem, Question and Solution Entities to **not** be fetched from the database.

Note the Question and Solution tables are connected to the Problem table. I'm not 100% sure of this but I think this means I don't need to add an .Include.

Ideally I would like the selects that EF causes to be issues to not include the Notes column.

Comment: Show what you are traing to do?

Comment: is that homework? what have you tried?

Comment: not quite sure what you are asking here?  you want to just select the `Notes` column from your `Problem` table?

Comment: I would like to fetch everything except Notes columns from the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use table splitting feature of EF. Create a `Problem(PK+all fields except for Notes)` and a `ProblemNotes(PK+Notes)` entities. Then querying against Problem should satisfy your needs.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj715645.aspx

With Entity Framework table splitting you can separate the properties that might contain very large amount of data into a separate entity and only load it when required.

Answer (score 0):

You might use .Select(...)  to make avoid fetching redundantly data from db. The code below illustrates how to fetch list of Problems with only ProblemId and Title fields:

```
var result = context.Problems.Select(problem => new { ProblemId = problem.ProblemId , Title = proble.Title }).ToList();
```

Using of .Select above will generate SQL query "SELECT p.ProblemId,p.Title from dbo.Problems as p".
Using of .List will retrieve data (it will not be dependent on context anymore )
Your might cast resulted set to Problem type ,eg:

```
var newResult = result.Select(x=>new Problem() { ProblemId = x.ProblemId, Title = x.Title } )
```